# `npm install <folder>` doesn't behave the same as `cd <folder> && npm install`

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a source tree like this:

```
myapp
├── nodestuff1
|    └── package.json
└── nodestuff2
     └── package.json
```

nodestuff1/package.json includes this:

```
"prepublish": "npm install ../nodestuff2"
```

nodestuff2/package.json includes this:

```
"devDependencies": {"uglify-js": "2.3.x"}
```

My workflow is supposed to be `cd myapp/nodestuff1 && npm install`, which should first install nodestuff2 followed by nodestuff1. However...

- running `npm install` in `myapp/nodestuff2` installs devDependencies, whereas
- running `npm install ../nodestuff2` **does not** install devDependencies.

For now I changed the `prepublish` script to cd to `nodestuff2` and run `npm install` there, then cd back to `nodestuff1` and run `npm install ../nodestuff2` so that it gets copied to `nodestuff1/node_modules`.

Is this a bug? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, understand that the semantics of "cd someproject && npm install" means "install someproject's `dependencies` and `devDependencies` so I can run it and/or develop it" as opposed to "npm install ../someproject" which means "install someproject in the current directory so I can use it from my project or from the repl", which does not install `devDependencies`. These make sense to me personally but that may or may not be intuitive to you, but in either case, that's how npm works.

Now, for your packages, if I understand what you are trying to do is pre-bundle nodestuff2 within nodestuff1 when you publish it to npm. Don't do that. Instead, just list nodestuff2 as a `dependencies` of nodestuff1 in `nodestuff1/package.json`. Are you trying to do something unusual here? If you provide the larger context of what you are trying to accomplish, it will be easier for people to post answers. My impression is you are working against the grain of npm but you haven't provided enough context for me to really assess what you are doing.

Comment: That difference makes sense now. This is a private repository that isn't getting published to npm. In the end I don't really need `nodestuff2` bundled into `nodestuff1/node_modules`, but it's making organization easier.